# Запись const unsigned char в Label

Tags: c++, sqlite, qt4

Спарсил информация из БД(sqlite) использую модуль на с++ sqlite3. Данные приходят в типе:

```
const unsigned char *id;
id = sqlite3_colum_text(stmt, 0);
```

Данные приходят но заместо кирилицы кракозябры. Как мне преобразовать всё это дело в нормальную кодировку(например в UTF-8) и вывести в label? Работаю с QT4.

Comment: Ну, для начала нужно разобраться - вы там строку получаете в виде однобайтных символов ASCII или все-таки кодовые точки Unicode и если да, то в каком виде - UTF8, UTF16 или UTF32. А затем из массива байтов при необходимости можно сделать строку. Но для этого придется соответствующий кодек искать: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14131127/qbytearray-to-qstring

Comment: А если попробовать QObject::trUtf8()

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В зависимости от того как вы открыли базу данных кодировка по умолчанию будет UTF-8 (для `sqlite3_open()` и `sqlite3_open_v2()` ) или UTF-16 ( для `sqlite3_open16()` ). Но можно использовать `sqlite3_colum_text16()` - она в любом случае возвращает UTF-16.
Далее можно делать примерно так:

```
int column = 0;
std::wstring str;
int len = sqlite3_column_bytes(stmt, column);
const wchar_t* c_str = static_cast<const wchar_t*>(sqlite3_column_text16(stmt, column));
if (c_str && len > 0)
    str.assign(c_str, len);
else
    str = L"";
```

Answer (score 1):

Чтобы получить строку в utf-8, её и положить туда (в БД) надо в utf-8. У БД там всё прозрачно.